# no results found plugin carrot2+elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch-plugin, carrot2

Good afternoon!

Can you help me please with some error? I had old version 1.3.4 of Elasticsearch and installed plugin Carrot2 Clustering plugin 1.7.0. I upgraded Elasticsearch to version 1.5.0 and plugin Carrot2 Clustering plugin 1.8.0.

Now I'm trying to create cluster in plugin carrot2 using plugin head of Elasticsearch. When I write in plugin head POST http://localhost:9200/name_index/_search_with_clusters

`{"search_request":{"fields":["message", "url"],"query":{"match":{"_all":"play"}},"size":100},"query_hint":"play","algorithm":"lingo","field_mapping":{"message":["fields.message"], "url":["fields.url"]}}`

I get results similar to results, that is described in examples in documentation in plugin carrot2. But when I try to create cluster in plugin carrot2, I get "no results found" (I tried with two different indexes and there is the same situation)

If I write `{"search_request":{"fields":["CONTENT", "url"]....`  I don't get in plugin head results with content, in mapping I have "message" instead "content".

Could you explain me please, what mistake it can be?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I've just updated my ES to 1.5.1 and everything seems to be working just fine. Could you provide a file with your index and query that doesn't work (ideally curl commands that would just import the content of the index).

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/crypto_test1/message/1/'-d '{"userName":"sirius","message": "Any updates on this? I'd like to offer a 50BTC bounty for implementing bitcoin: URIs in the main client.","id":"62824363619321520123447399604952602615", "url":"https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5171.0%3Ball"}
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/crypto_test1/message/2/'-d '{"userName": "sirius","message": "I've started coding this based on Freenet's Library plugin. I'll let you know when I have something that works. Slides from my presentation at Bitcoin Cafe Helsinki: http://www.rvl.io/mmalmi/identifi", "id":"173456646277059498504241103998526335207", "url":"https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=130137.0"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/crypto_test1/message/3/'-d '{"userName": "Blawpaw","message": "Interview with the Bitcoin Authenticator Development Team http://bitcoinist.net/interview-bitcoin-authenticator-developmentteam/", "id":"132270701711270767638103374518766971434","url":"https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=927838.0"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/crypto_test1/message/3/'-d '{"userName": "Blawpaw","message": "BitPay Introduces the Bitcore Playground http://bitcoinist.net/bitpay-introduces-bitcore-playground/", "id":"47851523789233207364389394815669084579","url":"https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=956260.0"}'
```

This query doesn't work :

```
{"search_request":{"fields":["message", "url","id","userName"],"query":{"match":"_all":"bitcoin"}},"size":100},"query_hint":"bitcoin","algorithm":"lingo","field_mapping":{"message":["fields.message"], "url":["fields.url"],"userName":["fields.userName"],"id":["fields.id"]}}
```

It returns message, userName, id, url in plugin _head, but it doesn't return results in plugin carrot2.

Did I write right queries, that you asked for?

Answer (score 0):

```
    json_data = json.dumps({
        "search_request": {
            "_source" : [
              "field1"
            ],
            "size": 30
        },
          "field_mapping": {
          "title": ["_source.field1"]
        },
        "query_hint": "",
        "algorithm": "lingo"                          
    })
    r = requests.post("http://localhost:9200/esindexName/_search_with_clusters", data=json_data, headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'})
    #print(r.text)
    clusterList = json.loads(r.text)['clusters']
```